# OpenLDAP olcMirrorMode

Tags: openldap

I am trying to use the Openldap dynamic configuration. I have an error being displayed as I try and add in the following :

```
add: olcMirrorMode
olcMirrorMode: TRUE

error(80)
additional info: <olcMirrorMode> database is not a shadow
```

Can anyone explain how to rid this error and what I need setup in order for the olcMirrorMode to be added in the daemon configuration?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problems, so hopefully this might help.

Mirrormode should be set up only on databases that you want to replicate, and the olcMirrorMode should be set *after* you've set up any and all syncrepl commands.

Assuming you're trying to do [n-master replication](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#N-Way%20Multi-Master)
Set up your syncrepl statments.

Once thats done turn on mirrormode. The catch for me was that I had to do a modify/add rather than a straight add to get it to accept mirrormode:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config     
changetype: modify 
add: olcMirrorMode 
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure OpenLDAP like below on first Server.

```
[root@dhcp200 ~]# cat /etc/openldap/slapd.conf |grep -v '^#' |grep -v '^$'
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
allow bind_v2
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload  syncprov.la
loglevel sync
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw      secret
directory   /var/lib/ldap
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
index entryCSN              eq
index entryUUID             eq
serverID 2
syncrepl      rid=001
              provider=ldap://192.168.122.204:389
              bindmethod=simple
              binddn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
              credentials=secret
              searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"
              attrs=",+"
              schemachecking=off
              type=refreshAndPersist
              retry="1 +"
mirrormode TRUE
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100
```

Configure slapd.conf like below in Second server.

```
[root@test6 ~]# cat /etc/openldap/slapd.conf |grep -v '^#' |grep -v '^$'
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
allow bind_v2
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
modulepath  /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload  syncprov.la
loglevel sync
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw      secret
directory   /var/lib/ldap
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
index entryCSN              eq
index entryUUID             eq
serverID 1
syncrepl      rid=001
              provider=ldap://192.168.122.200:389
              bindmethod=simple
              binddn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
              credentials=secret
              searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"
              attrs=",+"
              schemachecking=off
              type=refreshAndPersist
              retry="1 +"
mirrormode TRUE
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100
```

If you want to use cn=config method,  then convert it to cn=config format using

```
# rm -rvf /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
# mkdir /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
# slaptest -f slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
# rm slapd.conf
# chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
```

Start service of slapd on both servers.

```
# service slapd start
```